# Selecting an alternate style with fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I've got a font with two styles showing up in `fc-list`, corresponding to two TTF files:

```
Humanistic:style=Regular
Humanistic:style=Cursive
```

How can I select the Cursive style in fontspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check font names with `otfinfo -i <font-file>`.

In that particular case you can use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec,blindtext}
\setmainfont{Humanistic}
\newfontface\humanisticcursive{Humanistic Cursive}% Create a new font face for the Cursive style
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\humanisticcursive{\blindtext}% Apply the new font face
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah! That was easier than I thought :-)